# SubmitChanges Get back record immediately

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, submitchanges

I have a form that adds a record to the database. The primary key is auto incremented. I would like to have the web page redirect to the page that displays the information that was just entered.

For example, it would redirect to http://localhost/details.aspx?softwareID=1019 if 1019  was the next number generated.

Here is the code that submits it to the DB.

```
software software = new software
{
    EQCN = txtEQCN.Text,
    title = txtTitle.Text,
    version = txtVersion.Text,
    license = txtLicense.Text,
    expirationDate = txtExpirationDate.Text
};
db.softwares.InsertOnSubmit(software);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linq-To-Sql supports this out of the box.  After calling `SubmitChanges` the value of your propety that corresponds to your PK should have the new value.  In particular, the `IsDbGenerated` property of the corresponding `[Column]` attribute should be true (though if you ran it through the designer, it would already be there).